# Нужны ли запятые в скобках?

Tags: пунктуация

Я прошел мимо (,) к секретарю (,) и был впущен в кабинет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше поставить. Если это не уточнение, то что тогда?

Comment: Вот я тоже думаю, можно ли как-то извернуться и обосновать, что они здесь не нужны?.. Спасибо.